# Dictionary not remembering my selected dictionaries

Tags: iphone, ios, dictionary

When I select a word and use `Define`, I have to readd the same dictionaries that I've previously enabled. At first I thought each app had its own preferences, but it forgets every time, regardless of the app.

I noticed that changing the interface language will also decide which dictionaries are enabled by default (and thus not forgotten).

With English as the interface language I get the New Oxford English dictionary and the Apple Dictionary (what's this?). Like this, the Japanese dictionaries I want are always forgotten.

With Japanese as the interface langauge, I get the two Japanese dictionaries and the Apple Dictionary, but the New Oxford is suddenly disabled. Enabling the New Oxford will now be temporary, and I'd have to reenable it every time.

I'm running iOS 7.0.2. How can I make my settings stick?

Comment: I've seen various reports of this in other forums, but no fixes.  It may be a bug, but try a reset of your device.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid that didn't help (tried restarting with desired dictionary enabled, and also without to add as a fresh system). Er, did you mean a complete reset?

Comment: Reset is not restart, it is also not restore.  See http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1430

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even a reset doesn't work for me, but it seems like only the **Notes** app has permission to actually write to the dictionary settings, so you can solve this by:

1. Open the **Notes** app
2. Highlight a word and select Define
3. Touch the cloud icon for the dictionaries you want to enable
4. Open any other app and now those dictionaries will remain enabled

Answer (score 0):

Performing a "reset" (as per http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1430) appears to have resolved this issue for me!

Comment: It still happens for me in 8, and through a couple of resets. The bright side is that I just need to tap it again, and it loads after a number of seconds. I'm guessing they just take up too much memory for my iPhone 5.

Comment: On second thought, maybe it was always like that, but loads faster in 8.